# php I can`t create an input mask

Tags: php, database, input, mask, input-mask

I need to create an input mask using php to insert users in a database. The input mask must be like "U00000+number". I`ve been trying to do it but I didn`t succeed. Any help please?

Comment: I`ve been tryng to make a select to obtain the latest user inserted and then insert the new one with the key of the previous one +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you wanna gain here, either Uxxxxx or U00000x. But I guess you mean the first case, so:

```
$userid = __what_ever__;
$prefix = "U";
for($i = 0; $i < 5 - strlen((String)$userid); $i++) {
$prefix .= '0';
}
$userid = $prefix . $userid;
```

and for the what ever part, first get the last row of users, and do this to the user id part(ex U00456):

```
$userid = substr($userid, 1);
$userid = intval($userid)++;
```

Although it's good practice not to assign everything to the same $userid